# Split multidimensional list python and combine with another list python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

These are the lists:

```
[(3.8, 101.39), (1.597, 103.613), (4.7, 100.83), (4.804, 101.52)]
[(3.845, 101.396), (1.56, 103.613), (4.71, 100.9), (4.454, 101.161)]
[(3.847, 101.3), (1.59, 103.63), (4.76, 100.89), (4.45, 101.16)]
```

How can split them to become like this:

```
[(3.8, 101.39), (3.845, 101.396), (3.847, 101.3)]
[(1.597, 103.613), (1.56, 103.613), (1.59, 103.63)]
[(4.7, 100.83), (4.71, 100.9), (4.76, 100.89)]
[(4.804, 101.52), (4.454, 101.161), (4.45, 101.16)]
```

And eventually able to produce:

```
3.8 101.39 3.845 101.396 3.847 101.3
1.597 103.613 1.56 103.613 1.59 103.63
4.7 100.83 4.71, 100.9 4.76 100.89
4.804 101.52 4.454 101.161 4.45 101.16
```

My current code:

```
a, b, c = map(list, zip(*abc))
d, e = map(list, zip(*a))
```

Producing this result:

```
[3.8462193, 1.597, 4.7, 4.804 ]
[101.39, 103.613, 100.83, 101.52]
```

Which is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, all you needed to do was the use the first `map(list, zip(*abc))` which should correctly split the input to get the result you want. Although I think there's a bug in your code since that line should output 4 variables not 3.
Thus it should just be:

```
abc = [
        [(3.8, 101.39), (1.597, 103.613), (4.7, 100.83), (4.804, 101.52)],
        [(3.845, 101.396), (1.56, 103.613), (4.71, 100.9), (4.454, 101.161)],
        [(3.847, 101.3), (1.59, 103.63), (4.76, 100.89), (4.45, 101.16)] 
      ]

a, b, c, d= map(list, zip(*abc))

print(a) # [(3.8, 101.39), (3.845, 101.396), (3.847, 101.3)]
print(b) # [(1.597, 103.613), (1.56, 103.613), (1.59, 103.63)]
print(c) # [(4.7, 100.83), (4.71, 100.9), (4.76, 100.89)]
print(d) # [(4.804, 101.52), (4.454, 101.161), (4.45, 101.16)]
```

Also, you never defined what variable `de` was so I'm not sure I know exactly what you're trying to achieve but I hope this is what you were trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question, it should be either `a`, `b`, 'c` which is derived from the first line. I did exactly what you're doing, I'm getting this error : `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)`

Comment: And what is `abc` defined as? Because if it's defined the same as in my code then you shouldn't be getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a [Matrix Transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), you can achieve that with a list comprehension:

```
abc = [
        [(3.8, 101.39), (1.597, 103.613), (4.7, 100.83), (4.804, 101.52)],
        [(3.845, 101.396), (1.56, 103.613), (4.71, 100.9), (4.454, 101.161)],
        [(3.847, 101.3), (1.59, 103.63), (4.76, 100.89), (4.45, 101.16)] 
      ]
transpose = [[row[i] for row in abc] for i in range(len(abc[0]))]
```

And to print all that in a linear fashion, you can iterate over all the lists and insert a new line where approriate:

```
for line in transpose:
    for row in line:
        print(row[0], row[1], end="")
    print()
```

And you get the result expected:

```
3.8 101.393.845 101.3963.847 101.3
1.597 103.6131.56 103.6131.59 103.63
4.7 100.834.71 100.94.76 100.89
4.804 101.524.454 101.1614.45 101.16
```

Comment: Hi, you're missing some values here in expected result.. It should be `3.8 101.39 3.845 101.396 3.847 101.3` , you're missing `3.845 `  and `3.847 `, so on...

Comment: Nothing is missing actually, I didn't append a space so some number are merged together, for example `101.393.845 ` , `101.3963.847` and so on, all you need to do is to call `print` with an additional parameter like so: `print(row[0], row[1], sep=" ",end=" ")`, don't forget to mark the answer as valid if it helped you.